# SignalR and Uploading Files

Tags: jquery, html, signalr, uploadify

I want to upload a file to the server and than do some logic on it.
I want the user to be able to see the process steps as they happen. like for example:

- Uploading File (with %)
- File Uploaded
- Processing File
- Saving File
- Completed

Except of Uploading the file, I can do the rest with SignalR. But if I'll do the step of uploading with something like uploadify, than the hub (in signalr) wouldn't know which file to process.

I hope I have been clear, The only thing I had in mind to solve it is to do all the logic (including uploading the file) with SignalR, but I don't know if it is possible.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar and I'm just going to use a token (a guid id) to mark the file (i.e. the file name) and then have signalr pick up the file for processing via the token.

Comment: Sure, make methods for each bullet above on your server side and as you move to the next, emit a callback to the connected client (with associated JS functions) to have progress points you can represent in the UI however you wish